# how to add a custom javascript file to our theme

Tags: javascript

I add custom css files to my theme, but when I try to do the same for the javascript files,  they dont seem to work, this means that the javascript on the html files is working properlly, but if I transfer it to the custom javascript file it doesnt.
Am I adding the custom javascript file correctly to wordpress?

```php
if (! function_exists('custom_jsfiles')) {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_jsfiles');
    function custom_jsfiles() {wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', home_url().'/wp-content/themes/mytheme/custom-js.js');}
}
```

Comment: Why the `if (! function_exists('custom_jsfiles')) {` guard?

Comment: You can also use [get_theme_file_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/) to get the path to the file without hard-coding the /wp-content/ bit.

Comment: got it now, need to register it first and then use the wp_enquere_script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having this issue for months and I got it now running when I posted the question here. the issue is that the wp_enqueue_script needs to have the script file register first. So I have it working this way!

```php
if (! function_exists('custom_jsfiles')) {
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_jsfiles');
      function custom_jsfiles() {
      wp_register_script('custom_js', get_theme_file_uri().'/mytheme/custom-js.js');
      wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
   }
}
```

########################

updating the answer,
the path wasnt correct, also has jacob said, no need to register them
And now its working

```php
function ad_ficheiros(){
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/custom-js.js', array(), '1.15', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ad_ficheiros');
```

here the file is on a folder called inc inside the themes folder, also added two more parameters, the file version and if it is to be shown in the header or footer(false or true).

Comment: Also the Rup answer is correct, using the get_theme_file_uri is more commonly used, the  thing is that I am using this in a plugin.

Comment: You don’t need to register scripts before enqueueing them. That’s not the issue.

Comment: Had found the reason, wrong path and funtion parameteres missing. Thanks!